# Sharing on Facebook from iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

The Facebook share button displays as disabled in my application.

I have implemented as per the given URL
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#videos

I tried in many ways but there is no use. In the above specified URL, they did mention that 
"People who share should have Facebook for iOS client installed, version 26.0 or higher."

- May i please know what I should do to satisfy the above given requirement.

I am successful with sharing the Photos and links but I am stuck with the videos sharing.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As per the mentioned line provided in facebook docs:-**

> ```
> People who share should have Facebook for iOS client installed, version 26.0 or higher.
> ```

*The line simply means that the user who is using  your app to share video must have Facebook app installed in their device , the facebook version should be updated at least 26.0 or higher.*

Check whether  the "FacebookDisplayName"  matches with the name you entered in your Facebook Developer's App settings.

**Note :- The videos must be less than 12MB**

Comment: But I already installed the facebook native app, the version is 30.0